# Replacing the usual mean by the weak one

Tags: pr.probability

The mean of a non-negative random variable is just its $L_1$ norm. As such, it has a "weak" version:
$$ ||X||_{1,w} = \sup_{t>0} tP(X\ge t).$$
An immediate consequence of Markov's inequality is that the "strong" (i.e., usual) mean always upper-bounds the weak one, and the latter could be finite while the former infinite (such as $X=1/U$, where $U$ is uniform on $[0,1]$).

Question: is there a theory of convergence to the weak mean? Analogues of the CLT, strong law of large numbers, large deviations, measure concentration?

Edit. Let me elaborate. Obviously, the sample mean will *not* converge to the weak mean. What about the *weak* sample mean?

Comment: The model example here is the (extremely well studied) St. Petersburg paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Petersburg_paradox

Comment: I think the weak sample mean will converge a.s. to the weak mean iff $EX^2<\infty$; cf. e.g. Theorem A in shorturl.at/lLY59. However, a proof of this (which I don't have) will likely be too long for a usual MO answer.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Maybe we should write another paper! :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the trivial case, $\|X\|_{1,w}=\infty$, when the convergence will obviously hold. So, the conjectured necessary and sufficient condition is "$\|X\|_{1,w}=\infty$ or $\|X\|_2<\infty$", with a gap between the two terms of the disjunction "or".